How can I get the decibel (dB) level from sound URI in react native?
const stopRecording = async (coordinate: { latitude: number; longitude: number }) => {
    try {
      if (record) {
        await record.stopAndUnloadAsync();
        const uri = record.getURI();
        const dB = //dB level here
        if (uri) {
          setMarkers((prevMarkers) => [
            ...prevMarkers,
            { coordinate, audioUri: uri },
          ]);
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to stop recording', err);
    }
  };

Me and my group have been making a noise pollution map. This map allows users to record audio in their cities, which then the location and loudness of the recording will be entered into our database, allowing other users to see the noise pollution in that location. We are able to get the user's location, but we are having trouble getting the loudness, in dB, of the recording. Nothing has worked so far. How can we do it?

"Nothing has worked so far". Can you specify what you have already tried?
